# ros packages with C++14 lambda support

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, ros

Ok, since I'm working on a private project using ROS Framework, my motivation was raised by the new C++14 auto lambda feature (see this [link](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2014/08/28/cpp-14-lambda-tutorial/) for a better explanation).

the problem I am facing is that ROS framework is sticking to the old days [C++03 for it's compilation](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#c). So, how can I enable C++14 compilation support and how can I use the lambda functions ?

Here's a simple nodes for testing with the lambda function (in the subscriber node) :

- publisher :

  ```
  #include <ros/ros.h>
  #include <std_msgs/String.h>
  #include <std_msgs/Int8.h>
  #include <sstream>

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher string_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter_string", 1000);
    ros::Publisher int_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Int8>("chatter_int", 1000);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

    int count = 0;
    while (ros::ok())
    {
      std_msgs::String str_msg;
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << "hello world ";
      str_msg.data = ss.str();

      std_msgs::Int8 int_msg;
      int_msg.data = count;

      string_pub.publish(str_msg);
      int_pub.publish(int_msg);
      ros::spinOnce();
      loop_rate.sleep();
      ++count;
    }
    return 0;
  }
  ```
- subscriber :

  ```
  #include <ros/ros.h>
  #include <std_msgs/String.h>
  #include <std_msgs/Int8.h>

  //generic lambda to add two variables
  auto func = [](auto input) { return input + input; };

  void StringCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
  {
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", func(msg->data).c_str());
  }

  void IntCallback(const std_msgs::Int8::ConstPtr& msg)
  {
      int result = msg->data;
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%d]", func(result));
  }

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber string_sub = n.subscribe("chatter_string", 1000, StringCallback);
    ros::Subscriber int_sub = n.subscribe("chatter_int", 1000, IntCallback);

    ros::spin();

    return 0;
  }
  ```
- CMakeLists :

  ```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
  project(tutocpp14)

  find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    roscpp
    rospy
    std_msgs
  )

  catkin_package()

  include_directories( ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} include )

  add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
  add_executable(publisher src/publisher.cpp)

  target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
  target_link_libraries(publisher ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
  ```

Making the package after this configuration throw me the following error :

```
tutocpp14/src/listener.cpp:10:43: error: ‘func’ was not declared in this scope
   ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", func(msg->data).c_str());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that I can add the C++14 to ROS for my package compilation. Although this is not advised for publishing the packages.

> Use of C++11/C++14 features and filesystem/networking/etc... TS's (Technical Specifications) is allowed if they are checked for at configure time and equivalent functionality can be provided with the extra compiler features. Support for C++11 is now a compiler requirement, but the API of the packages included in desktop-full will not use any C++11-specific feature. External packages are encouraged to follow this guideline.

But, still that I am not intending to publish my work for now, so, I can get myself the permit to do so.

To get C++14 support for a ROS package, I have to set the -std=c++14 flag by adding the following lines in my `CMakelists.txt` file :

```
# check c++14 / c++0x
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++14" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX14)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX14)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++14")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++14 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()
```

this will check the existence of C++14 in the compiler and throw an error if not. Now, it works like a charm.

Hope that helps. Cheers.